# regex non-capturing and capturing groups and unexplained consumption

Tags: java, regex, capturing-group

I can't follow why these two expressions are different:

```
^(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?(?:\.(\d+))?$
applied to 1.0.3
group 1 =>1
group 2 =>0
group 3 =>3
```

which is expected. but if I try to generalize it for any series of `\d\.` then it doesn't work anymore:

```
^(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))+$
applied to 1.0.3
group 1 =>1
group 2 =>3
```

And strange enough to me everything but the first and last entries disappears:

```
^(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))+$
applied to 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9
group 1 =>1
group 2 =>9
```

Not exactly what I was expecting

Comment: Only last matching text is available in the 2nd capturing group. Groups are not dynamic, whatever groups you define that many you will get in matched result.

Comment: Repeated capturing groups behave like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following regex, that captures all the numbers with at least one digit and place them to separated groups:

```
(?<=^|\.)(\d+)(?=\.|$)
```

It works simple. Let's describe the parts of the regex:

- `(?<=^|\.)` is the positive lookbehind checking if the number `\d+` follows the dot `.` character (note is has to be escaped `\.`, otherwise it means any character) or the start of a line `^`.
- `\d+` is a number to be captured
- `(?=\.|$)` is the positive lookahead checking if the number `\d+` is followed by the dot `.` or the end of a line `$`.

Try it out at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zT2rK8/2) where is the more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I wasn't aware that capturing groups where not dynamic, as anubhava mentioned. Your solution shows other way of getting those values.

Comment: There is no need to use `+?` in the end, just `(?<=^|\.)\d+(?=\.|$)` is good enough.